# Aggregate by distinct character PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have column `zone_dist` in my table `parcel16` that contains land use codes (character).  My objective is to create a two-column table which in the left-hand column shows all of the distinct values and in the right shows the total count of those values in the table, in descending order. I have  tried with a basic query but cannot apply the sum function to a character value:

```
SELECT  zone_dist, SUM(zone_dist) AS quantity
FROM parcel16
GROUP BY zone_dist
```

returns the error:

```
ERROR:  function sum(character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  zone_dist, SUM(zone_dist) AS quantity
                           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How would one go about taking the counts of all distinct character values?

Comment: `count` don't `sum`.  Sum wan'ts to do math on character data, count simply counts occurances of zone_dist in parcel16.

Comment: Have you seen my comment to the selected solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want Count() rather than Sum(). Sum() adds the aggregate values (assumes int) whereas Count() will count the number of those values in which you group on.

```
SELECT  zone_dist, count(zone_dist) AS quantity
FROM parcel16
GROUP BY zone_dist
order by count(zone_dist) desc
```

Comment: (1) If `zone_dist` can be NULL it won't be count (2) Can be simplified using the `quantity` alias for the ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

Sum does math on string data.

Count simply increments by 1 for each occurrence of a zone_dist.  (thus it ignores nulls)

```
SELECT  zone_dist, count(zone_dist) AS quantity
FROM parcel16
GROUP BY zone_dist
```

Answer (score 0):

- If we have NULL values in column zone_dist, `count(zone_dist)`  won't count them and instead return `0`
- The `quantity` alias can be used in the order by clause

---

```
select   zone_dist, count(*) as quantity 
from     parcel16 
group by zone_dist 
order by quantity desc
```